# Title text color in actionbar not changing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to change the action bar title text color in a fragment.

I have include following methods in the activity:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        Log.d("action bar id","action bar id title previo: "+title);
    }
    public void setActionBarTitleTextColor(String color) {

        int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        Log.d("action bar id","action bar id "+actionBarTitleId);
        if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
            TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
            Log.d("action bar id","action bar id title: "+title);
            if (title != null) {
                title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            }
        }

    }
```

I can get the value for `int actionBarTitleId`, in this case it is:

```
D/action bar id: action bar id 16908676
```

But then in method `setActionBarTitleTextColor` the text from the TextView title is always recognized as null:

```
D/action bar id: action bar id title: null
```

This is how am I calling the method from the fragment, where `expl_especialidad_color_texto = #008080`

```
((MainActivity) getActivity())
                .setActionBarTitleTextColor(expl_especialidad_color_texto);
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setActionBarTitleTextColor()` from? Try doing it from the Fragment's `onActivityCreated()` callback.

Comment: @GavinWright, I am calling it from fragment's onActivityCreated()

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use Toolbar instead of the built-in ActionBar?

Comment: @GavinWright, not really,  but the project has already a lot of fragments, and I would prefer to keep the Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue using the following workaround for method `setActionBarTitleTextColor()`:

```
public void setActionBarTitleTextColor(String color, String title) {

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<font color='"+color+"'>"+title+"</font>",HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));


}
```